# Reverse order of stacked items

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way to reverse the order in which elements are displayed in an HStack?

I have something like this:

Button A | Text | **Button B**

But I'd like to have a setting for left-handed people so that the order would be reversed when set:

**Button B** | Text | Button A

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can manage this with switching layout direction, like in below demo

```
struct DemoView: View {
    @State private var isRegular = false
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button("Button1") {}
            Text("Text")
            Button("Button2") {}
        }
        .environment(\.layoutDirection, isRegular ? .leftToRight : .rightToLeft)
    }
}
```

[image: demo2]

Comment: That is also reverse all subviews recursively