# SwiftUI swap 2 views's places (once replaces the other)

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation

I have 2 views in SwiftUI in the HStack. I want to change their places, so 1. view jumps to 2. position and 2. to 1. position.

Here is some code example:

```
HStack {
    Spacer()
    LeftChannelView()
        .offset(x: swapLeftToRight ? calculatedOffset : 0.0)
    Spacer()
    RightChannelView()
        .offset(x: swapLeftToRight ? -calculatedOffset : 0.0)
    Spacer()
}
```

only `calculatedOffset` is unknown. I don't want to hardcode the value. I also don't want to calculate from `UIScreen.bounds`.

How should I calculate `calculatedOffset`?

Setting `offset` seems to work and also is animated nicely when I toggle `swapLeftToRight`.

```
withAnimation {
    swapLeftToRight.toggle()
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse order of stacked items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66230338/reverse-order-of-stacked-items)

Comment: Unfortunately, `layoutDirection` breaks the `offset`, when I try to keep the layouted view interactive for later. It throws some `Layer` exception on dragging. IMO not a good solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by carefully applying `matchedGeometryEffect` twice to each swappable view (so four times in total).

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

struct SwappyView: View {
    @Binding var swapped: Bool
    @Namespace var namespace
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Lefty Loosey")
                .matchedGeometryEffect(
                    id: swapped ? "right" : "left",
                    in: namespace,
                    properties: .position,
                    anchor: .center,
                    isSource: false
                )
                .matchedGeometryEffect(
                    id: "left",
                    in: namespace,
                    properties: .position,
                    anchor: .center,
                    isSource: true
                )
            Spacer()
            Text("Righty Tighty")
                .matchedGeometryEffect(
                    id: swapped ? "left" : "right",
                    in: namespace,
                    properties: .position,
                    anchor: .center,
                    isSource: false
                )
                .matchedGeometryEffect(
                    id: "right",
                    in: namespace,
                    properties: .position,
                    anchor: .center,
                    isSource: true
                )
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct DemoView: View {
    @State var swapped: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SwappyView(swapped: $swapped)
            Button("Swap!") {
                withAnimation {
                    swapped.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(DemoView())
```

The reason this works may be difficult to understand. The use of `matchedGeometryEffect(..., isSource: false)`, can reposition the modified view, but that repositioning happens after the view’s layout has been computed. (The `offset` and `position` modifiers also work this way.) So the frames captured by the `matchedGeometryEffect(..., isSource: true)` modifiers are the frames where the views would appear if there were no `isSource: false` modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any computations here, ever. On a simple level, the following code does exactly what you want:

```
struct SwapView: View {
    
    @State var leftChannelFirst = true
    
    var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    LeftChannelView()
                    Spacer()
                    RightChannelView()
                    Spacer()
                }
                .opacity(leftChannelFirst ? 1 : 0)
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    RightChannelView()
                    Spacer()
                    LeftChannelView()
                    Spacer()
                }
                .opacity(leftChannelFirst ? 0 : 1)
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation {
                    self.leftChannelFirst.toggle()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

You can add transitions, do matched geometry effects, or any number of advanced techniques. And, if you are worried that both "exist" on the screen at the same time, SwiftUI is highly optimized to not devote resources to invisible views.

Comment: What if behind `Left` and `Right` `ChannelView` there is an `AVPlayer` instance that downloads resources (even if paused, and works only if attached to views hierachy)? I would like to create only one left channel and one right channel.